# Is there a way to check if a SIM card is inserted in a Notebook?

Tags: powershell, networking, windows-10, netsh, rnotebook

We would like to do a statistic, over all notebooks, to check if they have a SIM card inserted.
Is there a way to check this?
I played already around with netsh, but maybe is there an easy query, just for checking if a SIM is inserted.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. This site is not meant to provide free code for you, rather for specific coding problems. I hope you solve your issue!

Answer (score 0):

How does this do, I am not that good at this, but maybe:

```
$comPortNumber = Get-WMIObject win32_potsmodem | where-object {$_.DeviceID -like "*05C6*"} | foreach {$_.AttachedTo} 

# 05C6 is the Vendor ID for Qualcomm, AttachedTo returns the Com port number

if (!$comPortNumber) { Return "No Gobi Card Detected!" }
else {

    $port = New-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort
    $port.PortName = $comPortNumber
    $port.BaudRate = "9600"
    $port.Parity = "None"
    $port.DataBits = 8
    $port.StopBits = 1
    $port.ReadTimeout = 9000 # 9 seconds
    $port.DtrEnable = "true"
    $port.open() #opens serial connection

    Start-Sleep 2 # wait 2 seconds until device is ready

    $port.Write("AT$")
    $port.Write("QCGSN `r") #writes your content to the serial connection

    try
    {
        while($myinput = $port.ReadLine())
    {
        $myinput
        }
        }

        catch [TimeoutException]

        {
    # Put handling code here
    }

    finally
    {
    # Put the clean up code here
    }


    $port.Close() #closes serial connection
}
```

Comment: i dont get any return from the first line command "Get-WMIObject win32_potsmodem" (with SIM inserted ofc.)